# Can I use this for loop to input 10 names into the arraylist i've created? Is there a better way to do this?

Tags: java

Can I use this for loop to input 10 names into the arraylist I've created? Is there a better way to do this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

   names = new Names[10];

   System.out.println("Enter 10 names: ");

   for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++){
        names.set(counter, scan.nextLine());
```

Comment: Why don't you try compiling and running it and let us know what results you get. I'd suggest checking out [ask] and [tour]. Particularly, it is important to ask questions with clear concise problem statements. "Will this code work" isn't a great one, especially when you can just go run it and find out. "Is there a better way to do this" is more on topic for something like codereview.se, but they have their own rules and community expectations as well.

Comment: as @CollinD already mentioned, compile the code, the compiler will tell you what's wrong with your code and you can easily find the solution on Google search

Comment: `names = new Names[10];`  - What is a `Names` Object? This will not work

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

System.out.println("Enter 10 names: ");

for (int counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++){
    names.add (scan.nextLine());
```